# In cell range, if any of the cell is empty than show that cell reference in the msg box

Tags: excel, vba

Iam very new to this vba exel, I have a table ranging (C5:J30).so in this range if any of the cell is empty, then I should get a msgbox “showing the cell reference of that empty cell” since I very new to the exel vba so I couldn’t write any code,as usual the stackoverflow  demands code attempt, so please anybody can help me in this regard

Comment: Your question contradicts itself.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: word-vba ??? Ranges???

Comment: sorry it should be exel vba

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend updating `ActiveSheet` to your sheet name

```
Sub findEmptyCells()
    Dim c

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("C5:J30")
        If IsEmpty(c) Then MsgBox c.Address
    Next c
End Sub
```